# jQuery - who is blocking my events?

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, mmenu

I'm using the **mmenu** plugin on a page that's based on **jquery-mobile**. Mmenu gives me left and right sliders which work fine except for when I try to open a 'mobile-style' popup window. These messages / events aren't getting out.

I have other popup windows on this page so I know that the popup code works but when I try to use the same code inside the `<li><a href="#popup" ... ></a></li>` framework for mmenu it does nothing.

Chrome script debugger doesn't show any errors. The styles and markup are the same between the working and non-working buttons (when viewed in the debugger).

---

**popup window**

```
<div data-role="popup" id="optionsDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="b"
  data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;" >
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Options</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    Some options go here?<br>
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline 
       ui-btn-b" data-rel="back">
       Cancel
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**button to open popup**

```
<a href="#optionsDialog" id="options_button" data-role="button" 
   data-mini="true" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" 
   data-transition="pop">
   Show popup
</a>
```

How do I go about finding my missing events?

Comment: not sure if its relevant, but I had faced similar issue with dialog when ajax was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: No idea what mmenu is doing to stifle this event but it was solved by scripting as follows:

```
$( "#options_button" ).click( function()
{
    $( "#optionsDialog" ).popup( "open", {} );
});

...
<li><a href="#" id="options_button" >Options</a></li>
```

plain old jQuery.